# How to update state in stateful widget in this case?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to change the SVG colours when I tap on it. I'm using a `boolean` in `parent widget` and setting it true/false when svg is tapped. Then I'm reading the `boolean` in my `child widget` and trying to set the colours for the child through `conditional logic`.
In `debugging`, I can see the `boolean` changes to `true` and `false` as expected. But the colour does not change. How to change colour in this case?

**Error:** `No errors, it just don't change colour when tap`

**Child widget**

```
class ToolSetButton extends StatefulWidget {
   
  final double width;
  final double height;
   ...

  const ToolSetButton(
      {Key? key,
       ...
      this.checkedColour = iconColourUnchecked,
      this.unCheckedColour = iconColourChecked,
     ...
      required this.buttonType ,  
 
      })
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ToolSetButton> createState() => _ToolSetButtonState();
}

class _ToolSetButtonState extends State<ToolSetButton> {
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Column(children: <Widget>[

InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.white,
                      onTap: () {
                        
                        widget.functionReceiverforButtonandSVG();
 
                        
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          
                          child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                            functionCalculatePadding(widget.height)),
                        child: FittedBox(
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            child: widget.icon == null
                                ? SvgPicture.asset(
                                    widget.svgPicPath!,
                                     
                                    color: 
                                    
                                    buttonChecked == true
                                    ? widget.checkedColour
                                    : widget.unCheckedColour
                                  )
```

**Parent widget**

```
class _ToolSetBottomState extends State<ToolSetBottom> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
          Row(
          
          children: [
            ToolSetButton(
                svgPicPath: svgVectorImagePath,
                buttonType: myButtonTypeList.SVGOnly,
                checkedColour: Colors.green,
                unCheckedColour: Colors.grey,
                
                width: 80,
                height: 80,
                  
               functionReceiverforButtonandSVG: () { funcForTapsandClicks (myButtonList.Two);}),


   
funcForTapsandClicks( myButtonList tappedOn) {

 if (tappedOn == myButtonList.Two ){
   print('Two');
    buttonChecked = buttonChecked == true 
    ?false : true;
     
   }
   
 
  }
```

Comment: You need to call `setState` to trigger the widget to update.

Answer (score 0):

Send the variable buttonchecked to the child widget instead of passing a function. In the child widget use
`setState((){ widget.buttonChecked = !widget.buttonChecked; });`

Comment: where do you place it? under the `onTap: ()`?  it says `buttonChecked is not defined for "toolSetButton"`

Comment: if (tappedOn == myButtonList.Two ){
   print('Two');
    buttonChecked = buttonChecked == true 
    ?false : true;
     
   } You can remove these lines and add the lines that I gave you